# Default Gateway IPv6 but IP set on IPv4

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4, sockets

I have a client who has a network setup. I have a couple of devices which work on the network using socket communication which I want integrated onto their network. There is a PC which is to be made the server to which my devices will communicate.

The problem I am facing is that the IP which is getting set by the DHCP is as below, where the default gateway is getting an IPv6 format. I am completely new to IPv6, and have been working on v4 till now without any issues.

Under Wireless Lan adapter: Link-local IPv6 Address: fe80::40e7:5740:6463:f539%13
IPv4 add: 192.168.1.xx
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway:
fe80::1%13
192.168.1.1

Now when I try to set the Ipv4 on static, the internet goes down and the PC goes out of the PC becomes unreachable. The devices which I am adding into the network get assigned IPv4 ips with the gateway set as : 192.168.1.1 .They are not IPv6 compatible.

I want to get a solution where I can implement the required network to implement my IPv4 devices to connect to the PC with a default gateway of IPv6.

I hope I have not created any confusion of any kind, let me know if so. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing. How did your machine get an IPv6 default gateway? If you mean to use IPv4 for your devices, then why are you messing with IPv6 at all?

Comment: The client already has a network setup previously, in which the connected PC is getting such a configuration. The reason I am trying to put it as static is because I cannot rely on a dynamic ip setting, my solution uses socket communication, which will go haywire if the IPs are not kept static. also as mentioned earlier, my devices are not IPv6 compatible, so they will not be able to send their messages anywhere due to the v6 default gateway already getting assigned

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to add device to someone else's network and they aren't working? You should have the person who owns/operates the network tell you what IP addresses to use and if they don't work, have them troubleshoot it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I am to add my devices to an already existing network,
Also yes, I am already on it, I could not get in touch with the network admin due to the weekend. I was hoping that someone has already experienced such a situation and I could save some time, because I do not have much of it.

Comment: If your devices do not use IPv6, then why is this even relevant here?

Comment: Why are you saying the default gateway is IPv6? The posted output has two default gateways one for IPv4 and one for IPv6. Having two default gateways would be perfectly normal for a dual stack deployment. However having a default gateway for IPv6 makes little sense when you only have a link-local address.